# react node csv postgres

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, csv

I am trying to process a csv file from react to postgres using node and express.  What is the recommended way of doing this?  Should I first upload the file onto the node server then do bulk insert (copy) into postgres or parse the csv in react and do the insert into postgres in the post request?  Thanks!

Comment: not sure about how much time and perf overhead the parse is going to have within react. Fastest way to insert day in PG is COPY>

COPY table(first_name,last_name,dob,email) 
FROM 'C:\tmp\table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

the parse portion is taken care of within pg.

Comment: upload the csv file and parse it in Node js is recommended. Because when you have huge csv then parse in front end is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.  I ended up uploading the file and used an extension call pg-format to do the bulk insert.